# Most computationally efficient way to prevent appending to string if appending variable is `None`

Tags: python

I am going through a JSON tree and appending particular values to a string.

Occasionally, the JSON object returns `None` and my code gives an error because Python does not allow appending `None` to a string.

In this case, what is the most computationally efficient way to prevent appending anything ? I will be going over hundreds of Millions of strings to speed is very important.

The most common solution I have found is to use filter(None, yourList) but that will not work for my case because I am going through different JSON objects with different tree structures and searching and extracting only certain values.

I am going through millions of JSON objects so speed and computational efficiency are more important than compactness of code, if that is a factor.

So in a nutshell

```
a = None

b = 'this string' + somefunction(a)

print(b)
```

> this string

This is the best I could come up with

```
def somefunction(strr):
    if strr == None:
        return ''
    else: 
        return strr
```

But I am wondering if this is the fastest solution. Since I am going through hundreds of millions of objects, any speed up will be very beneficial.

Comment: you can type if strr is None, I don't think there's any performance difference but is is more correct.

Comment: `b = "this string" + (a if a is not None else "")`? Python optimizes string concatenation with empty strings, and effectively functions as a no-op.

Comment: Function overhead is not inconsiderable. Do your check outside of a user-defined function, something like `b = 'this string' + (somefunction(a) or '')`.

Comment: @PMende It's a no-op, but it's a *run-time* no-op, so `str.__add__` is still called. The optimizer would apply to static concatenations like `"this string" + ""`.

Comment: @chepner so Function overhead is not inconsiderable, but isn't `somefunction` a function? So I think I'm missing something

Comment: @PeterForce it depends on whether `somefunction` is the thing returning the value, or if it's only there to wrap the conversion of `None` to `""`. If that's the case, then `b = 'this string' + ("" if a is None else a)` is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `a` to `''` if it is equal to None:

`a = str(a) if a is not None else ''`

And then add it to `b`:

`b = 'WAKA' + a`

Or, if you don't mind of converting zeros/Nones/empty-somethings to `''`, you can write something like it:

`b = 'WAKA' + (a if a else '')`

or:

`b = 'WAKA' + (a or '')`

I think these variants are nearly the fastest you can do in Python without C-code.